# Evenly partition a matrix into sets/chunks of (potentially non-contiguous) cells

Tags: python, matrix, partitioning, partition

Given a matrix of ints, I want to partition that matrix evenly into `n` chunks of cells in that matrix. The cells in each chunk do not need to represent a contiguous tile, line, etc. in the matrix. That means that the cells in a given chunk may not even be adjacent, and could be randomly scattered in the matrix.

The goal is to obtain chunks that are almost exactly the same size (in terms of number of cells), to the extent that is possible.

My preference is if the `i`th element of each chunk are as distant as possible.

I am thinking of implementing a generator, that given a chunk ID would return the next cell belonging to that chunk.

Here is what I have so far:

```
matrix = ...
shape = (len(matrix), len(matrix[0]))

def getNumCells():
    return shape[0] * shape[1]

def getIthCell(i):
    row = i // shape[1] 
    col = i % shape[1]
    return matrix[row][col]

def partition(n):
  chunkSize = getNumCells() // n
  for i in range(n):
    chunkSizes[i] = chunkSize
  chunkSizes[0] += getNumCells() % 5 # first cell is unfairly given what cannot be disstributed
  return list(range(n))

cursors = dict(((id, 0) for id in range(10)))
chunkSizes = dict(((id, 0) for id in range(10)))

def nextChunkCell(id):
  if cursors[id] == getNumCells()
  cell = getIthCell((cursors[id] + id) % getNumCells())
  cursors[id] += 1


def main():
  ids = partition(10)
  print(nextChunkCell(4))
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not sure how to implement the requirement that the chunks of cells be as distant as possible, a good approach seems to be to have each chunk be the same size, and comprising the contiguous cells that may span more than one row. Having it this way ensures that the `i`th element of each chunk is as far as possible from the `i`th element of all other chunks if the matrix were to be flattened to an array.

We track the number of cells consumed in each chunk, and for each call to the "next cell distributor" it returns the next cell in the chunk specified by the given id.

```
matrix = [
    [0.0,0.1,0.2,0.3],
    [1.0,1.1,1.2,1.3],
    [2.0,2.1,2.2,2.3],
    [3.0,3.1,3.2,3.3],
    [4.0,4.1,4.2,4.3]]
    
shape = (len(matrix), len(matrix[0]))
n = 3

completedCellCounts = dict(((cid, 0) for cid in range(n)))

def getCompletedCellCount(cid):
    return completedCellCounts[cid]
    
def completeCell(cid):
    completedCellCounts[cid] += 1

def getChunkNextPoint(cid):
    totalPoints = shape[0] * shape[1]
    chunkSize = totalPoints // n
    
    if ((cid == 0 and (getCompletedCellCount(cid) == chunkSize + totalPoints % n)) or (cid > 0 and getCompletedCellCount(cid) == chunkSize)):
        return None
    
    if (cid == 0):
        cell = getIthCell(getCompletedCellCount(cid));
    else:
        offset = totalPoints % n + chunkSize * cid;
        cell = getIthCell(offset + getCompletedCellCount(cid));
    
    completeCell(cid)
    return cell
    
def getIthCell(i):
    row = i // shape[1] 
    col = i % shape[1]
    return matrix[row][col]

def main():
    totalCells = shape[0] * shape[1];
    for cid in range(n):
        print("Cells for chunk {}:".format(cid))
        for j in range(totalCells // n + totalCells % n):
            print(getChunkNextPoint(cid))
        print()

main()
```

Output:

```
Cells for chunk 0:
0.0
0.1
0.2
0.3
1.0
1.1
1.2
1.3

Cells for chunk 1:
2.0
2.1
2.2
2.3
3.0
3.1
None
None

Cells for chunk 2:
3.2
3.3
4.0
4.1
4.2
4.3
None
None
```